# Django detail_route PUT. Empty body without trailing slash

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

This question is not for solving the problem rather to understand why it works this way.

I have `ViewSet` with some `detail_route` defined:

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    mgr_id = 'my_resource'

    @detail_route(methods=['put'])
    def history(self, request):
        print(request.body)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'my_resource', MyViewSet, 'r'my_resource')
```

Now if I call my API without trailing slash:

```
url = "http://myserver/my_resource/history"
requests.put(url, data=json.dumps({'test': 'passed'})
```

There is no error but in `history` `request.body` is empty.

However, when there is a trailing slash:

```
url = "http://myserver/my_resource/history/"
```

`request.body` suddenly transferred as expected.

I'd like to know why exactly this happens? No error but payload is empty... (Plus, this might help if someone struggles with that as well)